# Python CSV & Dict Writer- Write Specific Columns: Only writing the header

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I tinkered with some code that I found here to suit my needs where I only want to pull certain fields (columns) from a CSV and write to another file. I have a 150 line file in "cleanfile.csv" and I limited the headers-to-write to just two for simplicity of trouble shooting. I can add the rest back after I figure this out. The code does not error out but it only writes the header line to "outfile.csv". Any help would be grealy appreciated.

```
import csv

headers = ['Owner','Expiry']

with open('cleanfile.csv','r') as _in, open('outfile.csv','w') as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(_in)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out,headers,extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Try this code and post results   
`import csv
with open('cleanfile.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    print(row)`

Comment: Are the headers in both csv files the same?

Comment: If it is as simple as that.....My headers actually have single quotes around them in the file. I will try to accommodate for that.

Comment: To what Moses said - that should be your problem. Tested it out and it works fine for me

Comment: That looks to have worked!!!  However, it is printing a blank line in between each record "CR LF". Any ideas on how to eliminate that?

Comment: How exactly did you remove the quotes? On another point, if you still have the original file. Try adding this instead of removing the quotes:

`reader = csv.DictReader(_in, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

writer = csv.DictWriter(out,headers,extrasaction='ignore', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

Comment: I opted to include them in the headers by surrounding them in double quotes but I will likely just clean them up to have no quotes surrounding them.

Comment: Any ideas on the extra blank line being printed between records?

Comment: For the blank line issue in python 3, use newline='' when opening the file.  for example: `open(output_file_name, "w", newline='') as outfile`